# c# Regex find CPU clockspeed in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Regex is very new for me, so i have a question about. 
I'm searching for Regex pattern in C# to find **1.60GHz** in a string. Here is an example.

> Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU Z3795 @ 1.60GHz

I would like to have **1.60GHz**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Will there always be a decimal and will it always be GHz?

Comment: Yes, there always be a decimal and GHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution

**(\d+(?:.\d+) ?[Gg]?[Hh]?[Zz])**

thanks to everyone!

Comment: Not sure if this is intentional, but whole number will not work (3GHz will not match)

Comment: You're right. But in my case there no value without decimal. So the schema is X.XXGHz

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
  String pattern = @"(?<Freq>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)GHz";

  String source = "Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU Z3795 @ 1.60GHz";

  // 1.60GHz
  String result = Regex.Match(source, pattern).Value;
  // 1.60
  String frequency = Regex.Match(source, pattern).Groups["Freq"].Value;
```

Comment: They never said they wanted the frequency separately, why over complicate for someone who said they are a beginner?

Comment: @Alfie Goodacre: just to demonstrate how to do this (if required) and discourage from getting sub strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex

```
(\d+(?:\.?)\d+GHz)
```

Explanation:

```
( - //Start group
\d - //Any digit
+ - //Capture as many digits as possible before a non digit character
(?: - //Start a new group which we do not want to match seperately
\.? - //Match a decimal point literally or none at all
) - //End the non capturing group
\d+ - //Same as above
GHz - //Match the literal string "GHz"
) - //Finally close the group
```